# Can't assign a user to a database in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

I just installed SQL 2008 on a machine and when I run my website to add some data via a form, the browser says COMPUTER92/SQLSERVER can not login to database "mdbb" (computer 92 is my computer name) its is a valid Login under the server security -> logins for the server and the login COMPUTER92 says under its properties that its mapped to "mdbb" but under the users for "mdbb" it doesn't show COMPUTER92/SQLSERVER as a user! Any ideas?

Comment: what does your connection string look like?

Comment: I'v tried both below and they throw user error even though it says its mapped:

    <add name="SqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=COMPUTER92/SQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=mdbb;Trusted_Connection=yes"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />    

<add name="SqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=mdbb;Trusted_Connection=yes"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Could it be anything to do with the SID mapping changed because I have recloned the entire disk onto another computer? If so how can I make it recognise the current mapping?

Comment: @David Try deleting the mapping and recreating.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a little confusing to have a user with the same name as your database instance unless I am reading your error wrong.  Does it have a username in the error message as well?

As you are using a trusted connection I would say that you need to check what user your website is running under.  If you are running iis 5.1 (Win XP) then it will probably be ASPNET for iis 6 you can check this in the identity of the application pool I think by default it is Network Service but I am not certain.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you're referring to your server and instance using a forward slash - "COMPUTER92/SQLSERVER", but you actually need to use a backslash - "COMPUTER92\SQLSERVER". It's a longshot, but could this be causing the problem. Also, if you have SQL Profiler installed, can you run a trace and see if you see the connection attempt or the user's error message?

Answer (score 0):

Firs Of all check out your Connection string You are passing when connecting to the database.

Check that the User with which you are login is it a valid user in SQL Server then are you providing correct password??

why not you try with the user name and password connection rather then LOCALHOST connection.

Do the server name is correct or not??

Try To check all this out in SQL Server.

I think after checking this You will have the Solution...